# Optimize the function with OpenMP and drand48_r

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I need to optimize the following c++ code using openMp and replace the random number generator with drand48_r.

```
void MyClass::generateData()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      data_int[i] = MyRandomClass->getInt();
      data_int_help[i] = MyRandomClass->getInt();
      data_double[i] = MyRandomClass->getDouble();
   }
}
```

I tried to do it the following way:

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    struct drand48_data drand_buf;
    ...
}

void MyClass::generateData()
{
    double tmp;
    int i = 0;
    int temp_int;
    struct drand48_data drand_buf_local = drand_buf;

   #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(drand_buf_local) private(tmp)
    {
    seed = 1202107158 + omp_get_thread_num() * 1999;
    srand48_r (time(NULL), &drand_buf_local);
   #pragma omp for 
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      drand48_r(&drand_buf_local, &tmp);
      data_int[i] = (int)(tmp);
      drand48_r(&drand_buf_local, &tmp);
      data_int_help[i] = (int)(tmp);
      drand48_r(&drand_buf_local, &tmp);
      data_double[i] = tmp;

   }
}
```

But it does not work properly, more precisely it does not work faster depending on the number of threads, it is always the same. Maybe someone can help me with this?

Some other considerations:

I am running the `n = 30000000` and I can only add the parallelism in the
method `generateData()`.

When I call the generated method 30 times I can the following results:

```
Sequentially: 35318 ms with 2 thread: 42094 ms
```

and when I called only one time:

```
With one thread: 1066 ms  With two thread: 778 ms
```

Comment: One remark: you compute a per-thread `seed` but you use `time(NULL)` instead for initiating your RNG, so you'll have the same pseudo-random series for each thread. And then one question: how do you measure time? Is that elapsed or CPU time?

Comment: The is a good point (how the time is begin measured) forgot to ask that